# varchar m:d:Y H:i:s to date and datetime format conversion

Tags: mysql

I have converted varchar(modefied_date) to date and datetime formate like **varchar column** '26-12-2017 12:21:12' to **date** '2017-12-26' and **datetime** '2017-12-26 12:21:12'

locatio_table

```
id modefied_date         location
----------------------------------
1  26-12-2017 12:21:12   salem
2  26-12-2017 12:26:52   erode
3  26-12-2017 12:32:12   coimbatore
```

**modefied_date is varchar data_type**

I try this query

*query1:*

```
select location,date_format(modefied_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i %p') AS datetime from locatio_table where date(modefied_date) ='2017-12-26'
```

**this query shows empty result**

*query2:*

```
select location,date_format(modefied_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i %p') AS datetime from locatio_table
```

**this query shows location with *'null'*  result**

Answer (score 0):

query 1:

```
mysql> select location,date_format(modefied_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i %p') AS datetime from locatio_table where date(modefied_date) ='2017-12-26';
+----------+---------------------+
| location | datetime            |
+----------+---------------------+
| salem    | 2017-12-26 12:21 PM |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

query 2:

```
mysql> select location,date_format(modefied_date,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%i %p') AS datetime from locatio_table;
+----------+---------------------+
| location | datetime            |
+----------+---------------------+
| salem    | 2017-12-26 12:21 PM |
+----------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Your queries are giving the output as expected. None of the results are null / empty.